# Unsubscribe functionality in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to add unsubscribe functionality to my application. What is the best way to achieve it? I am thinking of adding a Boolean column, and depending on its true/false value I'll send a mail, but in this case I'll have to create a Boolean column for each type of notification. Is there any way to create a single column which will contain a hash, e.g.:

```
{:daily_notification=>true, :weekly_notification=>false, :yearly_notification=>true}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have a functionality where user can choose the type of notification he wants to receive.

Comment: I mean, why do want to create a single column to store the hash?  Why not just use three Boolean columns?

Comment: @amit kumar gupta:- As per your logic if she has to unsubscribe 50 emails in future then she has to add 50 columns and i think its unnecessary.

Comment: @deepika:- This will also help you http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing it in following ways in my application as i have lots of emails which i need to unsubscribe, so i am saving permission hash in `YAML format` in my users table like following

```
add_column :users, :permission, :string, :limit=> 500
```

To save the default permissions

```
user = User.first
default_permission_hash = {"send_daily_email"=>"true", "send_weekly_email"=>"true", "send_monthly_email"=>"true"}
user.permission = default_permission_hash.to_yaml
user.save
```

To update the permissions

```
user = User.first
permission_hash = YAML::load(user.permission)
permission_hash["send_daily_email"] = false
user.permission = permission_hash.to_yaml
user.save
```

In model

```
def is_permission_for?(email)
  permission_hash = YAML::load(self.permission) 
  permission_hash[email] == "true"
end
```

In controller

```
user = User.first

if user.is_permission_for?("send_daily_email")
  //send daily email
end
```

Comment: Every time you want to write a single bit of information, you have to load a YAML string, modify the hash, and rewrite the YAML?  And you have a 500 character column in your database to store 3 bits?  What happens when the user submits the form to update their preferences?  Instead of using the `params` hash you get in your controller, do you first convert that hash to YAML?

Comment: but problem with your suggestion is that suppose i want to unsubscribe   `n` emails i have to have that much columns in my database, and it makes my database heavier.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of serialize, what's the point exactly?  There are use cases to for storing a serialized object as a column in a database table, this isn't one of them though.  By the way, did you notice the second comment on that page, warning of performance issues when using serialize?

Comment: also, you can't query for all users with monthly/weekly/daily subscription.. much better to add a column

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Salil's suggestion would be to use a single [bitmasked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) column instead, let's call it `subscription_mask`.

To start, set up an array constant in the appropriate model (assuming `User`):

```
# user.rb
SUBSCRIPTION_TYPES = ["Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly"]
```

Additional subscription types could be added later on, so long as it's at the end of this array. This single column could store a large amount of flags very efficiently.

Then you can create a set of methods to interact with the bitmask, using the virtual attribute `subscriptions`:

```
# Make subscriptions attr_accessible so we can mass assign to it (useful for forms)
attr_accessible :subscriptions

# Basic setter, overwrites all subscriptions with an array of subscriptions
def subscriptions=(subs)
  self.subscription_mask = (SUBSCRIPTION_TYPES & subs).map{ |s| 2**SUBSCRIPTION_TYPES.index(r) }.inject(0, :+)
end

# Basic getter, returns an array of the set subscriptions
def subscriptions
  SUBSCRIPTION_TYPES.reject do |s|
    ((subscription_mask || 0) & 2**SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE.index(s).zero?
  end
end

# Check if a subscription is set
def has_subscription? (sub)
  self.subscriptions.includes? sub
end

# Add subscriptions to the current mask without affecting any others
def set_subscriptions (*subs)
  self.subscriptions = self.subscriptions | subs
end

# Remove subscriptions from the current mask without affecting any others
def unset_subscriptions (*subs)
  self.subscriptions = self.subscriptions - subs
end
```

There are a few methods there, but I've found them to be helpful in different situations.

With those methods, you can set a user's subscriptions like so:

```
@user.subscriptions = ["Weekly", "Monthly"]
```

And check if they have a subscription with:

```
@user.has_subscription? "Daily" # => false, in this case
```

If that same user subscribed for daily messages but unsubscribed from weekly ones:

```
@user.set_subscriptions "Daily"
@user.unset_subscriptions "Weekly" # => ["Weekly", "Monthly"]
# Or, to do both changes at once (you need to re-set Weekly though)
@user.subscriptions = ["Weekly", "Monthly"]
```

Another advantage with this approach is that it is possible to use this in queries. For example, to get all users with a Weekly subscription:

```
User.where("subscription_mask & ? > 0", 2**SUBSCRIPTION_TYPES.index("Weekly"))
```

It is a little messy, but could easily be cleaned up with a method or scope.

Comment: The [**flag_shih_tzu** gem](http://www.plugingeek.com/repos/pboling/flag_shih_tzu) uses this approach as well to handle multiple flag on an ActiveRecord model.